# Match columns by values stored as JSON in another table

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I have a table having a JSON datatype column which contains JSON array consisting of IDs for another table. I want to return matching rows from that other table.

For example:

```
SELECT members
FROM clubhouse
WHERE id = 55;
```

And it returns:

```
["7","8","9"]
```

I want the three rows from the `members` table with IDs 7, 8 and 9.

I'm thinking something like this, tho I know it won't work:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE id = [FOR EACH JSON(SELECT members FROM clubhouse WHERE id=55)];
```

How can I do this?

Note that I need all rows from a single query so I can do basic pagination. I am using MariaDB if that matters.

Comment: @SalmanA I don't mind the edit, but I liked "SQL" in the title

Comment: You're welcome to add it back. But SO does add the main tag in the "page title".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can try to use [`json_contains`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/) function to filter `JSON` value with subquery.

```
SELECT *
FROM members m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM clubhouse c
    WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(c.members, CONCAT('"', m.id, '"'))
    AND c.id = 55
)
```

[sqlfidde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=598087ebf0bb4c21f65f4095f7d37e40)

Comment: That is precisely and perfectly what I was looking for. And, it worked OOB, even when applying it to additional AND filters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`json_table`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_table/) function (requires MariaDB 10.6 or later) to convert the json to rows, then join:

```
SELECT members.*
FROM clubhouse
CROSS JOIN json_table(clubhouse.members, '$[*]' columns(
    id INT PATH '$'
)) AS j
INNER JOIN members ON j.id = members.id
WHERE clubhouse.id = 55
```

Comment: I like this, but the only reason I'm not marking it "correct" is because I prefer code that works with *both* SQL *and* mariadb. It is indeed another advantage of mariadb, and mariadb is tagged, so I upvoted, but I also want portability. FYI. That said, if someone had a non-mariadb solution for SQL, that would also be useful as long as we know it won't work there.